SSH to one VM connects back to the same (local) VM instead of the target VM
I’m experiencing a strange issue with SSH connections between two Ubuntu virtual machines (VMs) on VirtualBox. Here’s the detailed situation:

I have two Ubuntu VMs: myserver01 and myserver02.
When I check the hostname on each VM directly using the hostname command, it displays the correct hostname (myserver01 or myserver02).
However, when I SSH from myserver02 to myserver01, the terminal prompt shows username@myserver02 instead of username@myserver01, even though I expected to be connected to myserver01. This suggests something is wrong from the beginning of the SSH session.
After seeing the incorrect prompt, I ran the hostname command on the remote machine, and it also incorrectly shows myserver02, even though I initiated the connection to myserver01.
I also checked the IP address within the SSH session using ip addr show, and it seems like I am actually still on myserver02. It appears that despite trying to SSH into myserver01, I somehow remoted back into my own machine.
Interestingly, when I type exit to close the SSH session, the message connection to myserver01 closed appears, which suggests that the SSH session was supposed to be connected to myserver01, but something went wrong in the process.

Additional information:

Both VMs are using the 10.0.2.x IP range provided by VirtualBox’s NAT configuration.

Here is the content of the /etc/hosts file on both VMs:


myserver01 /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myserver01

10.0.2.4 myserver01
10.0.2.5 myserver02
10.0.2.6 myserver03

myserver02 /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myserver02

10.0.2.4 myserver01
10.0.2.5 myserver02
10.0.2.6 myserver03

Question: Why am I remoted back into myserver02 when I expect to be on myserver01?
Thank you for your help!

have you checked the IP address within the ssh session? is it the IP of the system you think you are connected to (eg are you sure you haven't remoted back into your own machine)?

@FrankThomas I checked using ip addr show within the SSH session and it appears I have indeed remoted back into myserver02. It seems the connection to the target server didn't happen correctly in the first place, so I’ve updated the main post to reflect this. What should I do to properly connect to the target server with SSH?

then clearly you have an issue resolving the IP of myserver01 on the system myserver02. a couple possible causes come to mind. first, review your host file, to make sure that it is correct. second, ensure that no other naming service (DNS, mDNS, etc) is providing a bad IP for myserver01. unfortunately using the host file makes things hard to test (since many apps will ignore it), so I generally set up a DNS server for the network, as its more reliably supported across applications and its configuration is easy to verify (nslookup, dig), but ssh should be expected to honor a host file.

The purpose of the Network Address Translation VirtualBox Networking Mode is to allow a VM to communicate with an external network while also isolating VMs from each other.
In other words: this is working exactly as designed and as described in the documentation [bold italic emphasis mine]:

Network Address Translation (NAT). If all you want is to browse the Web, download files, and view email inside the guest, then this default mode should be sufficient for you […]


Network Address Translation (NAT) is the simplest way of accessing an external network from a virtual machine. […]
A virtual machine with NAT enabled acts much like a real computer that connects to the Internet through a router. The router, in this case, is the Oracle VM VirtualBox networking engine, which maps traffic from and to the virtual machine transparently. In Oracle VM VirtualBox this router is placed between each virtual machine and the host. This separation maximizes security since by default virtual machines cannot talk to each other.

You can use any of the following Networking Modes, depending on your other requirements (or use multiple interfaces with different Networking Modes):

NAT Network,
Bridged Networking,
Internal Networking, and
Host-only Networking.

The documentation contains this handy table who can connect to whom using which Networking Mode:




Mode
VM→Host
VM←Host
VM1↔VM2
VM→Net/LAN
VM←Net/LAN




Host-only
+
+
+
-
-


Internal
-
-
+
-
-


Bridged
+
+
+
+
+


NAT
+
Port forward
-
+
Port forward


NATservice
+
Port forward
+
+
Port forward





How exactly is "not being able to talk to other VM" equivalent to "attempt of connecting to one will be redirected to this VM"?
